# Unable to use apt-get

Tags: apt

```
Version:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

I just tried to use `sudo apt-get install some_pkg` and figured out that impossible. I got the following error (full output):

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: undefined symbol: LZ4F_compressUpdate
```

Before this I did `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I just downloaded and installed `libstdc++` package as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb
```

But it didn't help. Can someone suggest something?

Comment: Can you post the full output of the command `sudo apt-get install <some-pkg>` rather than what you think are the interesting parts?

Comment: @CharlesGreen This is the full output

Comment: @CharlesGreen Solved. As the output suggested the problem was with `liblz4-1` dependecy. It had incorrect version.

Comment: @St.Antario Please post your comment as an answer to your own question. After 48 hours you can also click the check mark beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Good for finding the answer!  What is causing you to download and install libraries manually?

Comment: @St.Antario you never told anyone how you solved this.. I have this exact same issue and now you seem to have vanished.. It would be extremely helpful to others if you were explain what happened and how you fixed this error??

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had this issue and found that by manually downloading the liblz4-1 and installing with `sudo dpkg -i liblz4*` fixed the problem.

*Be warned - installing packages like this has the potential to break your system*

*But then just using apt has the potential to break your system!!*